# Running sql files to update database daily

Tags: sql-server, database, powershell, batch-file

I get a zipped file of sql dumps everyday. I unzip it, and then run this script everyday using a task scheduler to update the database.

```
@echo off
ECHO %USERNAME% started the batch process at %TIME%  >output.txt


for %%f in (C:\Users\Desktop\Crash\*.sql) do (
sqlcmd.exe  -S HUTRC1-HP -U sa -P hutrc@2121   -d test -i %%f >>output.txt)
exit
```

The database doesn't however get updated all the time. Let's just say it is not very reliable. There are some days when it is current, and other days when it's not current. Can't explain why. Is there more efficient script to update the database with? Preferably in powershell.

Comment: Do you want efficient, or reliable? They're different concepts. Before you start changing how you're doing this, I think you need to understand why your current process doesn't work properly every time you run it before you do anything else - otherwise, you'll likely just move your reliability problem into another language without fixing it.

Comment: @alroc I would be more interested in reliable at this point. I just want it to work with out failing. I know the code  works. I have tested it multiple times, and it works when I run it manually. Just don't know why it fails sometimes when I execute with task scheduler. I have researched a lot on it but to no avail.

Comment: If the code only works intermittently, look at the data. You're probably getting improperly formatted or unexpected data somewhere. Run `sqlcmd` manually with your input files, one at a time, to capture any output which includes error messages. Yes, this will take time. Proper troubleshooting often does.

Comment: Have you inspected the "output.txt" files from both successful and failing runs? Also, if there can be any spaces in the .sqlfilenames or in the path that is hardcoded, then you need to quote the variable as "%%f".

Comment: Can you create an SSIS package and run it that way? It gives better error handling, more reliable and most of your code can be reused.

Comment: @paul I inspected it. The weird thing was it ran correctly, the output.txt didn't look any different from the other ones that didn't fail. I was thinking of just using another script. That's why I posted to find out if there was another way of doing this.

Comment: @SalmanSyed I am kinda new to all of these. I googled 'sql files SSIS package' but nothing relevant popped up. Could you direct me on how to go about it? Thanks. Found a youtube clip. Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Creating an SSIS package will help you and achieve all that you want with better error handling.

There are multiple articles out there and a bunch of youtube videos. A youtube video can help you accomplish what you need in no time. Here are some articles that i quickly got off of msdn.

[How to create an SSIS package.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx)

[How to unzip files in SSIS package without any C# knowledge](http://www.radacad.com/ShowVideo.aspx?cpid=14&vid=6)

[How to automate an SSIS package.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dd440761(v=SQL.100).aspx)

Hope this helps.